# Range of percentages to values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to set up simple golf league spreadsheet.  Multiple categories with percentages given.

Would like to have them convert automatically when the percentages for each category are put in.  For example,

```
% of fairways hit
0-10% = 0 points
11-20% = 1 point
21-30% = 2 points
31-40% = 3 points
etc...…
```

I'd like to only have to enter the percentages to get the value

Answer (score 2):

Since your output is numerical and sequential you can simply use MATCH which returns the relative position of the general match:

```
=MATCH(A1,{0%,11%,21%,31%,41%,51%,61%,71%,81%,91%})-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula in a new column to display the score:
`=INT((A2-0.01)*10)&" point"&IF(A2>0.2,"s","")`

[image]